# Let $v,w$ and $v'$ be nonzero vectors such that $\langle v,v'\rangle=0$ and $\langle w,v'\rangle =0$ then $\langle v\rangle = \langle w\rangle$

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

Let $v,w,v'$ be nonzero vectors in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $v\cdot v'=0$ and $w\cdot v'=0$ then $\Vert v\Vert=\Vert w\Vert$.

how to prove this :

where to start $\langle v', v+w\rangle=\langle v',w\rangle +\langle v,v\rangle =0+0=0$.

[image]

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It’s not true

EG $v=(1,0)$, $w=(2,0)$, $v’=(0,1)$.

What is true is that $v=\lambda w$ $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: i said these are non zerovetctor...your example work only zero vector..study the question again please

Comment: (1,0) isn’t a zero vectors, you can also consider (2,2) (4,4)  and v’=(-1,1)

Comment: @suresh The answer is definitely sound.

Comment: It’s useful to make a sketch these vectors to convince yourself.

Comment: @ gimusi...look i added screen shot...@ G. Sassatelli

Comment: maybe the symbol stays for parallel vectors?

Answer (score 0):

The notation is quite confusing, but here I think $\langle v\rangle$ denotes the vector space spanned by $v$, while $\langle v,v'\rangle$ is the scalar product of $v$ and $v'$.

So the question really becomes : if two non-zero vectors of $\Bbb R^2$ are orthogonal to the same non-zero vector, then they must be colinear.

To prove it, it suffices to note that $\langle v,v'\rangle =0=\langle w,v'\rangle $ implies that $v,w\in \operatorname{span}(\{v'\})^\bot$, or equivalently that
$$\operatorname{span}(\{v\})\subseteq\operatorname{span}(\{v'\})^\bot\supseteq\operatorname{span}(\{w\}),$$
and use the fact that all these spaces are one-dimensional to conclude.